# How do I prove the identities of these questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I prove the identities of these questions?

> $$ 
> \frac{1+\tan^2 u}{1-\tan^2u}= \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u} \tag1 \\
> $$
>   $$
> \frac{\sin x + \sin(5x)}{\cos x+\cos(5x)} = \tan(3x) \tag2
> $$

Do I substitute the value for the sin or tan first when solving this? I'm confused.

Comment: Are you sure the second one is printed correctly? I bet it should be $\frac{\sin x + \sin 5x}{\cos x + \cos(5x)}$

Comment: btw, when asking next question please refer to [this guide on how to typeset math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You will need two facts, first the definition of tangent, second main trigonometric identity:
$$
\tan x= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\
\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1
$$

Using that you may transform $(1)$ as:
$$
\frac{1+\tan^2u}{1-\tan^2u} = \frac{1+\frac{\sin^2u}{\cos^2u}}{1-\frac{\sin^2u}{\cos^2u}} =\\
= \frac{\frac{\cos^2u + \sin^2u}{\cos^2u}}{\frac{\cos^2u - \sin^2u}{\cos^2u}} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u} \cdot \frac{\cos^2u}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u}
$$

The original $(2)$ which is:
$$
\sin x + \frac{\sin 5x}{\cos x + \cos 5x} = \tan 3x
$$
is false as shown in another answer (take $x={\pi \over 4}$ for instance). Here is a [visualization of LHS and RHS](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/89o5do5acn)

Comment: In my opinion, you should have let him doing both. You left the hard one to him...

Comment: @nicomezi I was going to update the answer, but another user has already shown that the second one appears to be false

Comment: As I did the work, the first one turned out to be true and the second was also true. Or is the first one false?

Comment: @User231 now both identities in the OP are correct. You've missed the parentheses when typing the identities for the first time. Namely you wanted $\sin x + \frac{\sin 5x}{\cos x + \cos 5x} = \tan 3x$, which is clearly false. But it has been fixed since.

Answer (score 1):

A very common strategy is to rewrite the expression and take the common denominator. Usually, this leads to an expression which can be simplified more easily.

The most commonly used identity is the Pythagorean Identity, or

$$\color{blue}{\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta = 1}$$

which is used in almost all such questions. It is also important to note the obvious $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, which also helps greatly.

$$\frac{1+\tan^2 u}{1-\tan^2u} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u} \tag1 \\$$

$$\frac{1+\frac{\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}}{1-\frac{\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u}$$

$$\frac{\frac{\cos^2 u+\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}}{\frac{\cos^2u-\sin^2 u}{\cos^2 u}}= \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u}$$

$$\frac{\cos^2u+\sin^2u}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u}$$

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u} = \frac{1}{\cos^2u-\sin^2u}$$

The second identity is just incorrect and false.

$$\color{red}{\sin x+\frac{\sin(5x)}{\cos x+\cos(5x)} \neq \tan(3x)} \tag2$$

Take $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Clearly, the RHS becomes $\tan\frac{3\pi}{4}$, which becomes $-1$. However, the LHS is undefined as $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\cos\frac{5\pi}{4}$ becomes $0$.

**Edit**: It has been mentioned in the comment below that perhaps it was a typo on your part. In this case, the following identity has to be proven:

$$\frac{\sin x+\sin(5x)}{\cos x+\cos(5x)} = \tan(3x) \tag{2}$$

Here, you use what are known as the [Sum-to-Product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities):

$$\color{blue}{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta = 2\sin\bigg(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\bigg)}$$

$$\color{blue}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta = 2\cos\bigg(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\bigg)}$$

Using these, you get

$$\frac{2\sin(3x)\cos(-4x)}{2\cos(3x)\cos(-4x)} = \tan(3x)$$

$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)} = \tan(3x)$$

$$\tan(3x) = \tan(3x)$$

Comment: I believe there is a misprint in the OP.  Since $\frac{\sin x + \sin (5x)}{\cos x + \cos(5x)}$ is indeed equal ot $\tan(3x)$

Comment: In that case, the Sum-to-Product identities would be the way to go.

Comment: Indeed, the terms will cancel resulting in $\sin 3x \over \cos 3x$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I will edit the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:
$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(u)-\sin^2(u)}
=\frac{\cos^2(u)+\sin^2(u)}{\cos^2(u)-\sin^2(u)}.$$
Now divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^2(u)$.

Comment: Thank you! When I calculed, I got thst both were true. I'm not sure if its just the second one.